# MIPS get the data from txt file

Tags: assembly, mips

I have a .txt file that contain 64 hex number. My task now is to store those number into register to do calculation. For example:

```
0x3e77904b
0x4027e6e7
0x3f5de12d
0x3fc4137f
0x3e754280
0xbfaa1dd9
```

I know how to open, read, close the file

```
          .data
fileName: .asciiz "C:\Python\Python38-32\64point.txt"
fileWords: .space 1024
          .text
          .globl main
main:
#Open file
li $v0, 13
la $a0, fileName
li $a1, 0
syscall
move $s0, $v0
#Read file
li $v0, 14
move $a0, $s0
la $a1, fileWords
la $a2, 1024
syscall
#Print
li $v0, 4
la $a0, fileWords
syscall
#Close file
li $v0, 16
move $a0, $s0
syscall 

li $v0, 10
syscall
```

Anyone has the idea how to do it? Thank you.

Comment: You will need to convert from text to number. Process 1 character into 4 bits. Consult an ascii table and use shifting.

Comment: So I will you lw to load $a0 to a register and begin to convert it?

Comment: You'd iterate through the string one char at a time (so, `lb`) and convert each char to 4 bits, accumulating the result in a register.